# Could you explain why we should use "prefix.pop()" there?

Tags: python, recursion, cycle

Could you explain why we should use `prefix.pop()` in this code ?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

```
def generate_number(numeral_system: int, list_length: int, prefix=None):
    prefix = prefix or []
    if list_length == 0:
        print(prefix)
        return
    for digit in range(numeral_system):
        prefix.append(digit)
        generate_number(numeral_system, list_length - 1, prefix)
        prefix.pop()

generate_number(4, 3)
```

Comment: Unclear; what is `generate_number` supposed to do?

Comment: This is a popular procedure in backtracking.  The append is use to add branch to the search path and the pop is to remove the branch.  An alternative that doesn't use append or pop is: `generate_number(numeral_system, list_length - 1, prefix + [digit])`

Comment: @chepner, function supposed to do list kinda
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1] and etc.